# GRUB menu doesn't work with wireless keyboard

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, keyboard

I had a problem with the wireless US keyboard. With the wired keyboard, the GRUB loader worked fine, but when I switched to the wireless keyboard, the GRUB menu became irresponsive.

Marvin

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is simple, but it took me years to ponder. At one moment it just became obvious.

Apparently, I didn't have the USB keyboard and USB mouse enabled in BIOS settings. With the wired keyboard, it didn't harm the GRUB, but when I switched to the wireless keyboard with a USB dongle connector, it suddenly stopped working in the GRUB loader menu.

Setting the USB keyboard to "Enabled" in BIOS fixed the issue, and the GRUB loader started working again :-)

Marvin